# Checking js deep equality without regard to prototypes (preferably in lodash)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm using the lodash `isEqual` function for deep comparison of JavaScript objects.  It requires objects to have the same prototypes to count as equal, as the following session with the node REPL shows:

```
> const isEqual = require('lodash').isEqual
undefined
> isEqual({a:3},{a:3})
true
> class Foo { constructor(x) {this.a = x} }
[Function: Foo]
> isEqual(new Foo(3), new Foo(3))
true
> isEqual({a:3}, new Foo(3))
false
```

Is there a simple way to do deep comparison disregarding prototypes?  It should still do special comparison for dates; I just want, in the cases where lodash would do a recursive comparison, that it doesn't care if prototypes differ.  Obviously I could code it myself, but I was using lodash to not have to do that sort of thing.  I also thought of doing

```
isEqual(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1)), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj2)))
```

Maybe it is all right, but it seems gross.

Comment: You can just use `JSON.stringify({a: 3}) === JSON.stringify(new Foo(3))` in last example;

Comment: That doesn't work.  Most browsers will give different results for `JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2})` and `JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not "a simple way", but it can help:

```js
function eq(a, b){
    if(!_.isObject(a) || !_.isObject(b)) return 'Error! Only for objects.';
    var keysA = Object.keys(a).sort();
    var keysB = Object.keys(b).sort();
    if(!_.isEqual(keysA, keysB)) return false;
    for(var i = 0, l = keysA.length; i < l; i++){
        if(
            ( _.isObject(a[keysA[i]]) &&  _.isObject(b[keysB[i]]) && !eq(a[keysA[i]], b[keysB[i]])) ||
            (!_.isObject(a[keysA[i]]) && !_.isObject(b[keysB[i]]) && a[keysA[i]] !== b[keysB[i]]) ||
            ( _.isObject(a[keysA[i]]) !== _.isObject(b[keysB[i]]))
        ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

eq({a: 1}, new Foo(1));         //true
eq({a: 1}, new Foo(2));         //false
eq({a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 2, a: 1}); //true
eq({a: 1, b: 3}, {b: 2, a: 1}); //false

eq({a: {a: 1}}, {a: new Foo(1)})//true
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks to me like this solution is going to break down on Dates and maybe in other cases I haven't considered (or maybe not).  I think if I were going to go the route of defining a more complicated function like this, I would either start with the lodash implementation and modify it or possibly do something based on lodash's `isEqualWith` function.  Also, I have seen some "canonical JSON.stringify" functions that order the keys.  For now, though, the "gross" solution I mentioned seems to work OK, so I am sticking with that until it gives me problems :)